# Integrating quotient of an analytic function's derivative and itself

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic with $|f(z)|\le 1$ on the disk.

Consider something like the integral

$$\int_\mathbb{D} \frac{|f'|^\alpha}{|f|^\beta}dA $$

Where dA is the area measure, with $\alpha,\beta\in (0,\infty)$.

Is it possible to get a handle on when these sort of integrals are finite, for various $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

For example, if $f' \in L^\alpha(\mathbb{D)}$, can anything be said?

Comment: Can we assume that $f$ has only finitely many zeros?

Comment: I think that is perfectly reasonable. 

Take $f_r:= f(rz)$ for $0<r<1$.  Then this is analytic on bigger than closed disk so has finitely many zeros in the disk.  Can we then use something like fatou's to get the general result?

Comment: That is, unless the bound would depend on number of zeros

Comment: @PhoemueX

I think I see how you would prove it for certain $\beta$ in the case where there are finitely many zeros, by realizing that $f'$ just has one lest multiplicity of each zero.  So we could view it as a sum of reciprocals of linear factors, plus a quotient of two nonvanishing analytic functions.  Then apply triangle inequality, and each one will be bounded.  I don't see a way to transfer this approach to the infinite zero case.  Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I also don't see how to lift it to the case of infinitely man zeros. I don't even know if the result holds in this case.